# File upload to database ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to upload file in database and once I attach file I see that DataFile show `NULL`. I try to figure out where is the problem, and while I debug I see that my DataFile constantly is show as `NULL`

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Upsert(TicketVM ticketVM, IFormFile files)
        {
            var userName = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
            var user = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

            if (ticketVM.Ticket.UserId > 0)
            {
                var usert = _db.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == ticketVM.Ticket.UserId);
                ticketVM.Ticket.ApplicationUser = usert;
            }
            else
            {
                var usert = _db.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == userName);
                ticketVM.Ticket.ApplicationUser = usert;
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (ticketVM.Ticket.Id == 0)
                {
                    if (files != null)
                    {
                        if (files.Length > 0)
                        {
                            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(files.FileName);
                            var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                            var newFileName = string.Concat(Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid()), fileExtension);

                            var objFile = new Ticket()
                            {
                                FileName = newFileName,
                                FileType = fileExtension
                            };

                            using (var target = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                files.CopyTo(target);
                                objFile.DataFiles = target.ToArray();
                            }
                            ticketVM.Ticket.Status = TicketStatus.Otvoren.ToString();
                            _unitOfwork.Ticket.Add(ticketVM.Ticket);
                        }
                    }
                    //}
                    //    ticketVM.Ticket.Status = TicketStatus.Otvoren.ToString();
                    //    _unitOfwork.Ticket.Add(ticketVM.Ticket);
                }
                else
                {
                    //ticketVM.Ticket.Status = ((TicketStatus)Convert.ToInt32(ticketVM.Ticket.Status)).ToString();                    
                    if (ticketVM.Ticket.Status.ToString() == "1")
                    {
                        ticketVM.Ticket.Status = "Otvoren";
                    }

                    else if (ticketVM.Ticket.Status.ToString() == "2")
                    {
                        ticketVM.Ticket.Status = "NaCekanju";
                    }
                    else if (ticketVM.Ticket.Status.ToString() == "3")
                    {
                        ticketVM.Ticket.Status = "Zatvoren";
                    }
                    _unitOfwork.Ticket.Update(ticketVM.Ticket);
                }
                _unitOfwork.Save();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            else
            {
                ticketVM.TicketTypeList = _unitOfwork.TicketType.GetAll().Select(i => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = i.Name,
                    Value = i.Id.ToString()
                });

                if (ticketVM.Ticket.Id != 0)
                {
                    ticketVM.Ticket = _unitOfwork.Ticket.Get(ticketVM.Ticket.Id);
                }
            }
            return View(ticketVM);
        }
```

So here is my Model

```
 public class Ticket
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Opis")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Kratak Opis")]
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Datum i vrijeme slanja")]
        public string DateAndTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

        [Display(Name = "Vrsta tiketa")]
        public int TicketTypeID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("TicketTypeID")]
        public virtual TicketType TicketType { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

        public int? ClientId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

        public string Status { get; set; } = TicketStatus.Otvoren.ToString();

        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string FileType { get; set; }
        [MaxLength]
        public byte[] DataFiles { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is ViewModel

```
 public class TicketVM
    {
        public Ticket Ticket { get; set; }

        public Client Client { get; set; }

        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TicketTypeList { get; set; }
    }
```

In my oppinion It seems that I forget to initialize DataFile somewhere but have no idea how and where. Does anyone see where I made mistake here ?

**UPDATE**

```
 public IActionResult Upsert(int? Id)
        {
            TicketVM ticketVM = new()
            {
                Ticket = new Ticket(),
                TicketTypeList = _unitOfwork.TicketType.GetAll().Select(i => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = i.Name,
                    Value = i.Id.ToString()
                }),
                ApplicationUser = new ApplicationUser(),
                Client = new Client()
            };

            var userName = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
            var user = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

            ticketVM.Ticket.ApplicationUser = _db.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == userName);
            var userEmail = ticketVM.Ticket.ApplicationUser.Email;

            if (Id == null)
            {
                return View(ticketVM);
            }

            ticketVM.Ticket = _unitOfwork.Ticket.Get(Id.GetValueOrDefault());

            if (ticketVM.Ticket == null)
            {
                NotFound();
            }
            return View(ticketVM);
        }
```

Comment: I would check the connection string.  You may have two copies of the database.

Comment: I have alredy check, posts are save in `db` but files not

Comment: When you send a HTTP you add a HttpPost. When you receive that data it is a HttpGet.

Comment: Yes, I get this point.

Comment: Did you fix the tag? [HttpPost]

Comment: What did you mean ? I didnt get sorry ?

Comment: Look at your posted Upsert().  You have a POST and if code is on server receiving the response then you need GET

Comment: I have alredy GET method. I update my code

Comment: How does your controller know what method to call?  The tag [HttpGet] is information to the controller to associate the receive data to the c# method.  When you send it is a POST to add body information and when you receive you use a GET to parse the body.

Comment: Doesn't metter. The `Upsert` method have alredy have `HTTPPost` attribute, when compile insert into `Controller` it will see that `Upsert` also have `GET` method and it will now that this is GET and POST method

Comment: There is something wrong with your GET.  The DATAFILE is received in the GET.  Is your problem sends in the DATAFILE or Parsing the DATAFILE in teh response controller?

Comment: I have no idea what my `GET` method should contain.DataFile is not storing in `db`. Thats the problem.I suppose that  I miss `.Add()` and `SaveChange()`

Comment: Put a break point in the controller and see if you are getting any body contents.

Comment: I just wnt to know, you can't receive file?

Comment: @jdweng Yes, I am getting body contents, but once I get contents it isnt store to db, so `DataFiles`,`FileType`, `FileName` are NULL

Comment: @Artavazd Yes, once I upload file in db is show as `NULL`

Comment: Here is ss [1] https://imgur.com/kORobXi [2] https://imgur.com/EiFeShE

Comment: `I am getting body contents, but once I get contents it isnt store to db, so DataFiles,FileType, FileName are NULL` You create an instance of Ticket object using `var objFile = new Ticket()`, and assign value for `FileName`, `FileType` and `DataFiles` property, then you seems not use this instance named `objFile`.

Comment: @FeiHan Can you explain a little bit deeper since I am begginer in `C#` please. I see that I use `Ticket` model which I add these tree field `DataFiles,FileType, FileName` and while I debug I see that the fileName contains file and everything is attach but in db is display as `NULL`